# Using Demand in Schema.org

Tags: seo, semantics, schema.org

I'm working on a website where **companies create posts to describe services they need**.

For me, this action is basically making a demand, in the sense of https://schema.org/Demand, and the demand is a for a https://schema.org/Service.

In addition to that, the Demand page on schema.org tell us :

> For describing demand using this type, the very same properties used
>   for Offer apply.

Given the last quote, the property named "itemOffered" in the "Demand" entity is very possibly what I want, but the name is very confusing (I rather use something called like "itemNeeded")...

Should I use the "Demand" entity with "itemOffered" for my use case ? Or something better exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the property name and the definition of [`itemOffered`](http://schema.org/itemOffered) doesn’t seem to match for using it in [`Demand`](http://schema.org/Demand), I guess the sentence you quote was added to assure users that it’s fine to use these for that purpose, and that it’s not an oversight.

And there isn’t any other Schema.org type suitable for representing demands; and for `Demand`, `itemOffered` is the only property that expects a `Service`. So this seems to be the only option.

So if an organization demands a certain service, this seems to be the intended way to represent it in Schema.org:

```
Organization seeks Demand
Demand itemOffered Service
```